# C# controling a panel

Tags: c#, forms, controls, panel

I'm using microsoft visual c# and making forms. I don't know if my vocabluary is correct but the idea is that when i create a panel using `Panel Figure = new Panel ();`
I cannot control it, i.e. change location. when I try

```
Point MoveLeft = Figure.Location;            
MoveLeft.Offset(-25, 0);
Figure.Location = MoveLeft;
```

it requires already existing panel named "Figure" and my newly created panel doesn't respond to commands.

also is there any way that when I create a panel, it's an already existing panel i.e to create the same panel as panel "triangle"?

Comment: Basically you could add the panel to the form in the designer and give it a name, than you can access it in the code of the form by addressing that name. Otherwise when you do it your way you would need to add it as a child of the form.

Comment: but I need many copies of same panel and i dont know exact number

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Panel on your form called "triangle", you can simply reference it in code like this

```
triangle.Left = -25;
```

If you create a new Panel you need to add it to the Form's Controls list

```
Panel Figure = new Panel();
Form1.Controls.Add(Figure);
Form1.Location = new Point(-25, 0);
```

Comment: ok, it creates new panel (as I suppose called Figure), but when later i write `Figure.Location = MoveLeft;` it moves the panel Figure, which I made by droping panel to form from toolbox. if i delete the one i droped manualy, it says 'the name "figure" does not exist'.

Comment: Be careful with your capitalisation. A panel named `figure` is not the same object as a panel named `Figure`.

Comment: my mistake, they are both called the same

Comment: Your naming is all screwed up. Don't call things "MoveLeft". Instead use, "leftPosition", etc.

Comment: If you drop the Panel onto the form from the toolbox and set its name to "Figure" using the Properties window, you can then reference it in code by writing Figure.Location = MoveLeft; you should not create a new panel by writing Panel Figure = new Panel();

Comment: but if I need another copy of the same panel, i.e. if the conditions occur, I already have one panel in left corner and I need to create another one which I would be able to move around.

Comment: Then I suggest you add two panels using the form designer and set the visible property of the second one to false. When the condition occurs you can then set its visible property to true and move it around.